# GTX 980M 8GB vs GTX 1070 8GB for a new gaming/workstation laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, gaming

So my daily driver of 3 years, the Lenovo G50-70, is on it's last legs, and I am in the market for a new high-end laptop to replace the G50-70.

I have found these two laptops that fit rather nicely in the my budget of $2000. The problem I face is that I cannot decide which one to choose over the other!

Here is the first Laptop --> [Asus G701](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N6ZNRZ8)

Here is the second Laptop --> [Asus GL702VS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N6KLBR1)

Here are the specs of the G701

- Core i7-6820HK
- 32GB DDR4 RAM
- GTX 980M 8GB
- 2 x 256GB SSDs in RAID 0
- G-Sync Monitor(17.3")
- Price -->  $1599 USD

And here are the specs of the GL702VS

- Core i7-7700HQ
- 16GB DDR4 RAM
- GTX 1070 8GB
- 512GB SSD + 1TB HDD
- G-Sync Monitor(17.3")
- Price --> $1999 USD

The deciding factor for me here is price to performance. On one hand the G701 has 32GB DDR4 RAM pre-installed, with a 512GB SSD included, but sports the 980m 8GB. Where as the GL702VS sports a GTX 1070 8GB, but only has 16GB DDR4 RAM.

What puts me off from the GL702VS is the price of the laptop alone, this doesn't allow me to buy extra addons for it later on, like say a 1TB SSD. So I am leaning towards the G701, mainly due to the fact that I will be able to buy upgrades for it at the same as purchasing the laptop altogether.

I do a lot of 3D rendering for buildings and structures, as I work at a engineering firm, so the GPU is kinda important in that regard, but I also want to game at a moments notice.

Which laptop should I get? The G701 with the older GPU but better spec? or the GL702VS with the better GPU, but lower spec? If not either? Can you recommend me a better spec laptop with a good GPU in it, but at a better price?

**On a side note**

I have considered a GTX 1080 laptop to satisfy, as well as Quadro workstation laptops, but these are either out of my budget or are not powerful enough to both game and work.

Comment: Note that a 980M is about as powerful as a 970 (desktop) card. Thus the GPU power is roughly a 1070 compared to a 970.

Comment: @SEJPM So I am essentially comparing a 1070 to a 1070?

Comment: No, [a 970 is significantly less powerful than a 1070](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-970-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1070/2577vs3609), I just wanted to give you a more useful comparison.

Comment: @SEJPM my bad. A bit of miscommunication there. Thank you for the insite though. Makes it a bit more clear now

Comment: "I do a lot of 3D rendering for buildings and structures" What applications are you using? Do you care about anything besides performance?

Comment: @JMY1000 I use applications like AutoCad, TurboCad and to a lesser extent, Maya, 3DS Max and Sketchup. Well, mainly yes. I also care for how long I will be able to use the laptop before I am to replace it with a newer model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my decision, after some time. I got the laptop with the GL702VS